# Spring Boot: can I create arbitrary new threads?

Tags: spring-boot

Is this kind of code in Spring Boot a good idea?

```
Thread t = new Thread(myRunnable);
t.start();
```

**Or is there a `ThreadFactory` that is better to use?**

```
Thread t = threadFactory.newThread(myRunnable);
t.start();
```

If so, what is it?

I do not wish to use some sort of ExectorService to manage the threads for me, because they do not fit my use cases.

Side note: This is a question for the [OptaPlanner](https://www.optaplanner.org/) open source constraint solver library - to document how users integrate best with stacks such as WildFly, Spring Boot, Android, ...

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/CustomizableThreadFactory.html and https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html